# I make a class of Textfield.But when I try to call value,it can't get the real value of the text in the textfield via controller

Tags: flutter

This is my code.When I try to get RxInput.value,I get nothing.How to deal with it?Where is the problem?
I want to make it easy for me to use the decorated textfield.So I build this class.How to solve it????
I am about to be crazy.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class RxInput {
  _RxInput rx;
  final String hindText;
  final bool obscureText;
  Widget get widget  => rx;
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController ();
  String get value => controller.text;
  RxInput (this.hindText,context,{this.obscureText = false}) {
    rx = _RxInput (hindText,obscureText,controller);
  }
}

class _RxInput extends StatefulWidget{
  final TextEditingController controller;
  _RxInput (this.hindText,this.obscureText,this.controller);
  final String hindText;
  final bool obscureText;
  @override
  createState () {
    return _RxInputState ();
  }
}
class _RxInputState extends State <_RxInput>{
  Padding data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    data = Padding (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          shadowColor: Colors.blue.shade200,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child:TextField(
            controller: widget.controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.hindText,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              alignLabelWithHint: true,
            ),
            obscureText: widget.obscureText,
          )
    ),
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do like this**

```
1. Create a Class with Meaningful Name for eg.Helper Class
2. And Implement below Textfield Method


Widget textField(String hint, TextEditingController controller,
    {TextInputType keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    bool obscure = false,
    VoidCallback onEditingComplete}) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 45,
    child: TextField(
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      obscureText: obscure,
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: textFieldPadding(),
        hintText: hint,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxLength)],
    ),
  );
}
```

And just simply use it by importing a particular class library put it wherever you want and let me know it is working for you or not?

Comment: Exactly I wanna include a controller in this class....So that I dont need extra variable in my program.

Comment: @Dorbmon so u can remove extra variables simple!

Comment: I am going to have a try.Thank you!